# Use Apollo server as a pass through of a query from client

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, apollo-datasource

I have a use case where I have `apollo-server-express` running with a React based `apollo-client`. I have an external `graphql-datasource` for some queries. Currently, I've configured `apollo-datasource-graphql` to be used as a data source for my `apollo-server-express`. However, this requires duplication of work on the resolver in Apollo as well as the resolver on my external `graphql` system.

Is there a way for me to pass queries made in the client through the Apollo Server and to the external `graphql` data source?

Comment: Apollo Federation ?

Comment: @xadm That seems to help but I'm not sure how I would write my resolvers if I need to pass the query to the external Graphql source

Comment: It links external graphql into your server, all external resources/resolvers should be available in main server - just configure it (docs?), no need to write any resolvers?

Comment: Apollo federation links multiple servers under your control into a single schema. It might not be the thing OP wants here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could access the GraphQL AST from the fourth resolver argument (`resolveInfo`) and pass it into a GraphQL client?

Here is some prototype code:

```js
import { print } from 'graphql/language/printer';

function forwardOperationResolver(root, args, context, resolveInfo) {
  return fetch('https://remote.host/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: print(resolveInfo.operation),
      variables: resolverInfo.variableValues,
    }),
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      if (response.errors) {
        // Handle errors
      }
      return response.data;
    });
}
```

Downside: This breaks a few things that usually work in GraphQL like partial results and error locations...